# Sudo Broken But Need pkexec

Tags: linux, terminal, sudo

So I'm having this problem where I can't use "sudo"

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I researched and my solution to solving this would be using this command

```
pkexec chmod 555 /etc/sudoers
```

But apparently I don't have pkexec

```
-bash: pkexec: command not found
```

And there isn't any google searches that would help me solve this problem now =[.

Anyone know why this is occuring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach I would take in this case, and as indicated **[here](https://askubuntu.com/a/745563/619102)**, is to boot into recovery mode (or "single user" mode), then fix the permissions on the `/etc/sudoers` file.

That answer is for Ubuntu, but the same approach should work regardless of distribution.

If you for some reason cannot boot into recovery mode, then I would suggest that you use a Live medium (CD, USB) and fix the permissions from there.

Comment: Don't forget `su`.

Answer (score 1):

Fix it on Debian releases using

> `apt install policykit-1`