# sudo /etc/sudoers is world writable

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, command

I did pkexec chmod 555 /etc/sudoers.d" does not work for me due to pkexec having a permission promblem, get the PID of the shell you are running pkexec in suing "echo $$" then log in another shell and do a " pkttyagent --process XXX" with the XXX replaced with the PID of the other shell.

After I do that, it said Not Authorized, I usually just switch to the root sudo su - without any password. How I can solve this issue with Linux Fedora 7.9v ?
Thank you.

Comment: Check the ownership and permissions of `/usr/bin/sudo`: it should usually have permissions 4755 (`-rwsr-xr-x`) and be owned by the `root` user - it cannot work unless both the permissions and ownership are correct. Note the `s` indicating the SETUID bit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sudo Broken But Need pkexec](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323617/sudo-broken-but-need-pkexec)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. i just checked ---s--x--x.   1 root root . how I can fix it I'm still new to the Linux command.